# To create Flag for a key based on a set of pair values present in Dataframe 2 - Python Problem

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Table A contains two columns - Col A & Anti Col A such that if the value from Col A comes in a dataframe for a ID, Anti Col A should not be present - If value 1 comes then value 4 should not occur.

Objective is to create a flag whenever such error occurs.

[image]

I have table B where in ID variable is the key and Col B should follow the table A rules. For ex: For ID "A", Col B contains 1,2 & 3 as values. But as per our table A, 2 should not occur along side 3, hence an error

[image]

Final Output will look like below -

[image]

This is a sample, the original data contains million of rows.

I was trying to create a flag for Col A and Anti Col A and find a solution using it with unsuccessful attempt

[image]

Part - 2
How to approach the problem if there are dates added along with existing condition i.e. the Anti column will work if the Start Date & End Date are active
Input data -
[image]

Final New Output - For ex for ID "B" 1 and 4 is anti rule for June 1 and June 2 only. While in our data they are coming on 5th June. hence the anti rule will not be applicable here
[image]

Solution As Given in the Comments worked earlier -

##### for each ID group in df2, pool all the anti col A for this group

##### then any value in current df2 group needs to be flag if they are in that pool

```
grouped = df2.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x['Col B'].isin(df1[df1['Col A'].isin(x['Col B'])]['Anti Col A'])).reset_index()
```

Adding the code to create the dataframe as mentioned above-

Dataframe - 1 & 2 as mentioned in the code

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6],
                   'Anti Col A': [4,5,2,2,1,7,1,3],
                   'Start Date': ['2021-06-01','2021-06-01','2021-06-01','2021-06-01','2021-06-01','2021-07-01','2021-06-01','2021-06-01'], 
                   'End Date': ['2021-06-02','2021-06-05','2021-06-02','2021-06-05','2021-06-05','2021-07-05','2021-06-05','2021-06-05']})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C'],
                   'Col B': [1,2,3,1,4,5,6,1,7],
                   'Start Date': ['2021-06-01','2021-06-02','2021-06-03','2021-06-04','2021-06-05','2021-05-06','2021-06-07','2021-06-08','2021-06-05'], 
                   'End Date': ['2021-06-01','2021-06-02','2021-06-03','2021-06-04','2021-06-05','2021-06-06','2021-06-07','2021-06-08','2021-06-09'],
                   'Flag_Old': [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1],
                   'Flag_New': [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]})
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you post code as text

Comment: could you change the dataframes into text instead of image, I can give a try for part 2

Comment: @Da Song - I have added the dataframes as text. Please let me know if any other information is needed to improve the question quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it works, name two dataframe df1 and df2, and assume df2 does not have duplicated value with same ID

```
# for each ID group in df2, pool all the anti col A for this group
# then any value in current df2 group needs to be flag if they are in that pool
grouped = df2.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x['Col B'].isin(df1[df1['Col A'].isin(x['Col B'])]['Anti Col A'])).reset_index()

df2['Flag'] = grouped['Col B'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Song , would you like to attempt the Part 2 of the problem? To deal with the details given the date caveat